# Continue counting after page 1

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have this simple counter php code and use it in Wordpress. Here is the code:

```
$counter = 0;
   while ($query->have_posts())
       {query->the_post();$counter++;
```

Which works fine. But when I go to page 2, then the counter resets and starts back at `1`. Is there a way that it continues counting on page 2, page 3 and so on?

the url in the browser address is: `/?sf_paged=2` for page 2 and `/?sf_paged=3` for page 3 etc...

Is there some `if` code I can do, like:

```
if $url = /?sf_paged=2 {
    $counter2++; }
else if $url = /?sf_paged=3 {
    $counter3++; }
```

something like that?

Comment: What are you counting? Posts? The query always has a counter ($query->found_posts, if it was WP_Query - look here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Init your counter  like this

`$counter = $_GET['sf_paged'] ?  intval($_GET['sf_paged']) * $posts_per_page : 0;`

Then `$counter++` will be what you want.

Comment: I'm now using: `$counter = $_GET['sf_paged'] ?  intval($_GET['sf_paged']) * $posts_per_page : 0;
 while ($query->have_posts())
 {
  $query->the_post();
 $counter++;`

But the counter is still starts back at 1 on the second and third page? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Of course you have replaced $posts_per page by the real variable containing this right value ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the number of all the posts in the query, use:

```
$query->found_posts
```

If you want to see how many posts are there from page 1 to n (where 'n' is the current page) I suggest use a simple multiplication:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$postnum = $paged*$query->posts_per_page;
```

Or you could try to store it in a $_GET parameter, a cookie or a sessionStorage / localStorage. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this one should works fine

```
<?php
$i = 0; //counter
$post_in_page = 4; //number of posts in loop
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; //pagi
$guide = "post_type=post&posts_per_page=$post_in_page"; //loop option
?>
<?php query_posts($guide.'&paged=' . $paged); while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  
<?php 
$i++; //here counter
if(get_query_var('paged') != 1){ // here if current page not first page
echo get_query_var('paged')*$post_in_page+$i-$post_in_page; // that's it :D 
}else{
echo $i;
}
?>    
<li>
<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
<br />
</li><!--End Loop-->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<ul class="pagnum">
<li><?php next_posts_link();?></li>
<li><?php previous_posts_link(); ?></li>
</ul><!--End pagnum-->                      
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
```